# Check if value of one column exists in another as a whole word pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to compare 2 columns of a dataframe to see if value of one exists in another as a whole word. for eg. if I have df1 like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [56, 4098, 672, 78, 90, 5601, 1],
       'col2': ['56 some string', '40 some string', 'some string 672', 'some string 78 some', np.nan, 'some 5601 string 298 some', 'some random 212 string']})
```

I want to add a column 'match' to it like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [56, 4098, 672, 78, 90, 5601, 1],
       'col2': ['56 some string', '40 some string', 'some string 672', 'some string 78 some', np.nan, 'some 5601 string 298 some', 'some random 212 string'],
       'match': [True, False, True, True, False, True, False]})
```

I found it could be done with str.contains but its giving me an error:

```
df1['match'] = df1['col1'].str.contains(dfData['col2'])
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I also tried converting 'col2' into a list (using str.split()) and then do str.contain check but end up with nothing.
Can someone please help me with what I'm going wrong.

Comment: Try : ``df1.assign(match = [str(left) in right for left, right in zip(df1.col1, df1.col2)])``

Comment: does col2 always match a number?

Comment: @sammywemmy your solution works on the example I gave but not on the actual dataset I have. the error is "TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable". I checked the 2 column types and they both are object.

Comment: Kindly update your shared code to reflect these new information

Comment: @sammywemmy I have updated the dataframes to show the cases where I'm receiving the error. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Try this: ``df1.assign(
    match=[str(left) in str(right).split() for left, right in zip(df1.col1, df1.col2)]
)``

Comment: Yes this works. thanks. Can you please put it as an answer as well. I'll accept and close it.